# Parseint with leading zero Java

Tags: java

i've got a string, for example "1024", i need to remove one character from it as like this:
024
124
104
102

after i must find the minimum value, so, my minimum value is 024, and  i want it to insert into an array, or Vector, whatever.

so, my code is:

```
void generateMin() {
        String number = "1024";

        Vector<Integer> variations = new Vector<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            String variation = number.replace(number.charAt(i), '\0');
            int numberVariation = Integer.parseInt(variation);
            variations.add(numberVariation);
        }
}
```

However, when i am running it i get an error :java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 024"

The problem is that when i am doing:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("024");
```

it returns 24, without errors, but there i am getting an error, so, can you help me? what is the problem ?

Comment: Please consider using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`

Comment: Why are you using `replace()`? Why are you replacing with ``\0``? I don't think either of those does what you thing they do. E.g. if `number = "121"`, then first iteration of the loop will replace `1` with ``\0``, resulting in `number = "\u00002\u0000"`, which is not a valid number, because the `NUL` character is not a valid digit. Also note how it replaced both 1's at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error specifies that the `NumberFormatException` is for `" 024"` since the character was not removed, try this to get the variation:

```
String variation = number.substring(0,i) + number.substring(i+1);
```

Comment: Did you try replacing with "" (the empty String)?

Comment: Sorry, Add this to convert charAt value to String: Character.toString(